# HL7 FHIR implementation of animal owners

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are working on implementing the FHIR API in a veterinary health care system. One question that has come up is which resource type we should be using for the owner of the animal (patient). In the context of the animal it is easy to see that the owner information can go into the contact of the Patient resource.

However, an animal owner is quite often referenced outside the context of an individual patient. So that leads me to RelatedPerson. The description of the RelatedPerson resource gives an example of "The owner or trainer of a horse", so it seems it might fit. However, one big issue with this is that a RelatedPerson can only be linked to a single patient. The relationship between animals and owners in the veterinary domain is many to many. So an owner often has more than one animal.

This issue led me to the Person resource. This at least gives a way to have multiple Patient's (animals) belonging to one Person (owner).

In either case we'll have to add a "percentOwnership" attribute as an extension to the resource since an animal can potentially have multiple owners.

If this is the way we should do it (using the Person resource), my next question is how would one search using the API for all Patient's linked from a given Person? If we used the RelatedPerson (which is probably not workable due to the limitation mentioned above), it seems like this search would use the relatedPerson compartment to search. However, there doesn't seem to be a person compartment in the spec.

Summary:

What resource to use for the owner of an animal?
How to search for all animals belonging to a particular owner?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want contact information, then Patient.contact is fine.  If you're interested in the owner as a potential actor (information recipient, informer, performer, etc.) then RelatedPerson will be necessary.  However, RelatedPerson is specific to a particular Patient's record (i.e. you'll have a distinct RelatedPerson instance for each animal).  To link all of the RelatedPerson instances together and say "this is the same person", you'd use Person.  To query, you'd query on Person where link matched one of the desired RelatedPerson records.  Then you'd need to do an include of Person.link and RelatedPerson.patient to bring back all of the animals